# JAXB marshaller to marshal super-class as root-element and use xsi:type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsi

I'm trying to marshal a sub-class as super-class with xsi:type information as the XML Root element attributes.

Currently this is what I have (let's say..):

- XMLDOCUMENTTYPE is a super class of XMLINVOICETYPE
- marshalling XMLINVOICETYPE will give me `<xmlInvoiceType>`
- Casting XMLINVOICETYPE instance to XMLDOCUMENTTYPE instance and then marshalling it would still give me `<xmlInvoiceType>`
- Creating a wrapper object annotated with JAXB annotation seems to do the trick, but now I have to grab the first child-node

e.g.:

```
jaxbWrapper.setXmlDocumentType(xmlInvoiceTypeInstance);
```

// will do the trick but extra root

What I'd like to get is as follow:

```
<XMLDOCUMENTTYPE ... ... xsi:type="XML_INVOICE_TYPE">
</XMLDOCUMENTTYPE>
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marshalling:

```
new JAXBElement(new QName("XMLDOCUMENTTYPE"), XMLDOCUMENTTYPE.class, xmlInfoiceTypeInstance)
```

Answer (score 0):

xsi:type is only rendered, if the type does **not** match the class.

Try this:

```
// create the type and add childs and attributes ...
XmlInVoiceType xmlInVoice = new XmlInVoiceType();
// map the element to object to force xsi:type 
final JAXBElement<?> object = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://your/namespace/xmlinvoice", "xmlinvoice"), Object.class, xmlInVoice);
```